# How to implement Map in singleton class?

Tags: java, singleton

I have the task to make a program about Florist's. I have to make a class PriceList, which is a singleton. I have also a following given testing function main:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 PriceList pl = PriceList.getInstance();
 pl.put("rose", 10.0);
 pl.put("lilac", 12.0);
 pl.put("peony", 8.0);
```

Looking on these pl.puts(), I decided to implement Map interface in class PriceList, but I don't know exactly how to do it, when I have only one object of this class and it has to be a Map. I have already written that much and don't know what to do next:

```
public class PriceList <String, Double>  implements Map <String, Double> {

private static PriceList instance = null;

protected PriceList() {}

public static PriceList getInstance() {
    if (instance == null)
        instance = new PriceList();
    return instance;
}

public void put(String string, double d) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Sounds like homework...  What is exactly the question?  Have you tested it yet?

Comment: yes, it's a homework, but it's bigger than this. I have a testing class FloristsTest, which I can't change and I have to implement necessary classes to make it work. I haven't tested it yet

Comment: People aren't keen to help with homework here - it is for you to research, but besides that, BrunoDM gave a good answer.

Comment: OK, thanks for information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Singleton is correct! Instead of implementing the map interface, you could create a Map attribute inside your class and delegate the put method to the maps'put method. Take this example:

```
public class PriceList{

    private Map<String, Double> map = new HashMap<String, Double>();

    private static PriceList instance = null;

    private PriceList() {}

    public static PriceList getInstance() {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new PriceList();
        return instance;
    }

    public void put(String string, double d) {
        map.put(string,double);       
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought that I have to make a singleton class, and the only object of this class as to be a Map. This solution i more convenient, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is simplier ways to do this :

- add a Class PricePerFlower with attributes Flower and price, and put a List as an attribute in your PriceList class.
- or just add a Map attribute in your PriceList class.

Answer (score 0):

Map implementations are usually quite sophisticated (at least the efficient ones).

If you **absolutely** have to use this outline (`PriceList` as singleton and implementing `Map` interface), I would suggest using an existing Map implementation under the hood:

```
public class PriceList <String, Double>  implements Map <String, Double> {

    private Map<String, Double> map = new HashMap<>();
    private static PriceList instance = null;

    protected PriceList() {}

    public static PriceList getInstance() {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new PriceList();
        return instance;
    }

    public void put(String string, double d) {
        map.put(string, d);

    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyContext {
    private static MyContext ourInstance = null;
    private HashMap<String, String> translatedValue;

    public static MyContext getInstance() {
        if (ourInstance == null)
            ourInstance = new MyContext();
        return ourInstance;
    }

    private MyContext() {
        translatedValue = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void addTranslatedValue(String title, String value) {
        translatedValue.put(title, value);
    }

    public String getTranslatedValue(String value) {
        return translatedValue.get(value);
    }
}
```

Using

```
MyContext myContext = MyContext.getInstance();
myContext.addTranslatedValue("Next", valueTranslated);
System.out.println(myContext.getTranslatedValue("Next"));
```

Result

```
valueTranslated
```